# Need Lightweight .NET SMTP implementation (assembly or source)

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I am writing a small application that will receive messages to process over smtp port 25.

I am looking for an .NET assembly that I can incorporate that will listen to port 25 and talk SMTP.  I invision that when a message arrives some event is triggered where I can read the message and process it.

Esstentilly I need to "Act" like a SMTP server but apart from receiving the message I don't need any more functionaly that you would find in a full blown SMTP server.

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at this: [CodeProject: SMTP and POP3 Mail Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/smtppop3mailserver.aspx)?

Comment: I was looking for somthing a bit more "lightweight"  

1.  Listing on Port 25
2.  Talk RFC821 (SMTP)
3.  When a message is received, fire an event and let the event handler process the message

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't able to find anything that light weight, but it wouldn't be too difficult to write it from scratch (I'm sure that's not the answer you're looking for).

Comment: Implementing RFC821 is never light-weight. And if you implement less than RFC821 (e.g. a fake SMTP daemon that only understands the most basic "receive mail for user" scenario) you should not expose this SMTP daemon on the public Internet.